# Nuxt Layout update data on every route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am new to Nuxt/Vue and am getting confused about how data works between different pages. I want to display a light or dark logo depending on if I am on the index page or not. When navigating between pages the data doesn't update the route name so the logo doesnt change: Layout page below.

```
<template>
  <main>
    <img v-if="page != 'index'" src="~/assets/img/logo-white.svg">
    <img v-else src="~/assets/img/logo-dark.svg">
    <nuxt />
  </main>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
         page: this.$route.name
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Any help would be great.
Thanks,
Jamie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `computed property` instead of `data`,  `$route` is reactive and will trigger a computed update.

```
computed: {
  page() {
    return this.$route.name
  }  
}
```

You could also just access `$route` in your template.

```
<img v-if="$route.name != 'index'" src="~/assets/img/logo-white.svg">
```

Answer (score 6):

In a nuxt layout, every page is rendered in place of the `<nuxt />` tag.

You are setting the reactive property `page` in the layout which is mounted only once in the beginning, and all other pages are rendered inside it later. So when a page change occurs the layout doesn't re-mount and the value of `page` remains the same.

You can add a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on the route like this:

```
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        page: this.$route.name
      }
    }
    watch: {
     '$route': function (value) {
       this.page = value.name
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

So, now everytime the route changes, `page` will updated with the new name of the route.

Comment: this.$route in data of a Nuxt application does not work! It throws an error!